# What's the fastest way to find a rhomb in a 2d array?

Tags: algorithm

Here's the visualization of my problem:

[image]

I need to find most valuable rhomb stored in a square.
I'm thinking on this for few days but till now, I didn't manage to find anything else than using **'for loop'** and checking every possible rhomb. What do you guys think about that? Is that the only way I can make it? :P thanks :)

Comment: Search problems on a grid like this often have [Dynamic Programming](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Dynamic_programming) solutions.  *"It is applicable to problems with overlapping subproblems which are only slightly smaller"*

Comment: Do you have a link to this problem perhaps on spoj.pl or something like that ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here's my idea:

**1st iteration**, you traverse the matrix, but diagonally. You start at the most upper left place where you can fit your rhomb (or rhomb's side), and you look at the elements covered by the rhomb's size.

- you start by examining elems (0,1) and (1,0) *(a)*
- next you examine (0,2) and (1,1) *(b)*
- (1,1), (2,0) *(b)*
- (0,3), (1,2) *(c)*
- (1,2), (2,1) *(c)*
- ...

I hope you get the examination order. What you do with this elements is you sum them up: *e(0,1) + e(1,0) = 11*, *e(0,2) + e(1,1) = 3* and so on. You have to notice that when you're working with elements on the same line (the ones marked with the same letters above), you don't have to calculate the sum all over again: there's one element going out, and one coming in, so you access only two elements to get the new sum.

**2nd iteration**, you traverse the matrix diagonally, but from a different side. You start from the upper-right corner, and work on sums previously calculated. So, the first pair you'll examine will be at *(0,3), (1,4)*. You do the exact same things you did before: you calculate sums again.

Now, at the end of the 2nd iteration, every processed field actually contains the sum of the **sparse rhomb** which has an upper corner in that field. An example for 3x3 rhomb is in the image below:

[image: Sparse 3x3 rhomb]

**3rd step** From the image, it can be seen that a *sparse rhomb* of size *n* is "missing" another sparse rhomb -- the one of size *(n-1)*. And iteration 1 and 2 are exactly the procedure to find a sum for all the sparse rhombs of size *n* in the image. So, as a 3rd step, we run 1st and 2nd iteration again, but not with the size we're searching for (*n*), but instead, with size *(n-1)*. *Note* that the "search" for size 1 equals the input matrix (e.g. if n=2, for the 3rd step you don't have to calculate anything).

At last, the sums interesting to you for a 3x3 rhomb at the top-position (0,2) is a sum at (0,2) from the first two iterations, and the sum at (1,2) from the 3rd step. You can add these two together: for every element in the result matrix of the first two passes at position (x,y), you add the element at position (x,y+1) from the 3rd step result matrix. 
Now you just have to find the maximum, and you have the answer about both maximum value and position of the rhomboid.

You do all this in 4 passes (you can keep track of the maximum as you are calculating the 2nd pass) -- so this would give the complexity of `O(4*n^2) = O(n^2)` where `n` is the size of the square's size.

Hope it's clear, if I made a mess out of my answer, please ask for clarification.

---

**Example for 2x2 rhomb**

**1st pass**

```
 -1 11  3  7  5     * / * * * 
 -1  9 14 12  3     / * * * *
 -1 12 18  4  6     * * * * * 
 -1 11  3  6  2    * * * * * 
 -1 -1 -1 -1 -1     * * * * *
```

**2nd pass**

```
 -1 25 15 10 -1    * * * \ *
 -1 27 18 18 -1    * * * * \
 -1 15 24  6 -1    * * * * *
 -1 -1 -1 -1 -1    * * * * *
 -1 -1 -1 -1 -1    * * * * *
```

**3rd step**

Since *n=1*, the 3rd pass does not need to calculate anything, the output of the third pass is the input matrix

```
 1  2  2  2  2
 9  1  5  3  1
 8  9  9  2  3
 3  9  2  3  1
 2  1  3  1  1
```

Now, we just need to sum up the output of the 2nd iteration with the output of the 3rd step (shifted one place up). We get:

```
 -1 26 20 13 -1    
 -1 36 27 20 -1    
 -1 24 26  9 -1    
 -1 -1 -1 -1 -1    
 -1 -1 -1 -1 -1
```

**answer**
The rhomb that has an upper corner at (1,1) is the most valuable one, with the sum 31.

*Note:* `-1` is a place where a rhomb side does not fit -- *undefined* sum. You can mark it in your program whichever way you want (especially if you can actually have negative values in your matrix). In the second pass, you can set any sum that has an *undifined* element to *undifined*.

*Note2:* No mater what the rhomb size, when you're sliding the rhomb-side through the matrix, one number always comes in while another comes out of the sum (except when you're entering a new line).

*Note3:* The first position of the rhomb in the 2st and the 2nd pass is marked in the array with `/` or `\`

---

**Example 3x3 rhomb**

Let me do a 3x3 rhomb on the same matrix, to show that the complexity is `O(n^2)` (where `n` is the size of the square's size) in the general case, not just for the 2x2 rhomb.

Let's call the input matrix `z[][]`, the matrix after the first pass `f[][]` and after the second, `s[][]`

**1st pass**

1. `f[0][2] = z[0][2] + z[1][1] + z[2][0] == 11` *(a)*
2. `f[0][3] = z[0][3] + z[1][2] + z[2][1] == 16` *(b)*
3. `f[1][2] = f[0][3] - z[0][3] + z[3][0] == 17` *(b)*
4. `f[0][4] = z[0][4] + z[1][3] + z[2][2] == 14` *(c)*
5. `f[1][3] = f[0][4] - z[0][4] + z[3][1] == 21` *(c)*
6. `f[2][2] = f[1][3] - z[1][3] + z[4][0] == 20` *(c)*
7. `f[1][4] = z[1][4] + z[2][3] + z[3][2] ==  5` *(d)*
8. `f[2][3] = f[1][4] - z[1][4] + z[4][1] ==  5` *(d)*
9. `f[2][4] = z[2][4] + z[3][3] + z[4][2] ==  9` *(e)*

you visit every element at most once. Marked with distinct letters are sums on a same line. In the first sum of the line, you have to sum as many elements as there is in the rhomb's side, let's call it `m` for `m x m` rhomb. In every other sum of the line, you *always* have to access exactly 3 elements: the previous sum, the element that's going out (the one with the `-` sign), and the one that's going in (`+` sign).

```
 -1 -1 11 16 14 
 -1 -1 17 21  5 
 -1 -1 20  5  9 
 -1 -1 -1 -1 -1 
 -1 -1 -1 -1 -1
```

**2nd pass**

Then you do a similar thing in the second pass (I'm not going to write them out), you just have a little less elements.

```
 -1 -1 41 -1 -1 
 -1 -1 -1 -1 -1 
 -1 -1 -1 -1 -1 
 -1 -1 -1 -1 -1 
 -1 -1 -1 -1 -1
```

**3rd step**

This step is exactly the same as the *1st* and *2nd iteration* of the *2x2 example*. So, the sums of 2x2 sparse rhombs are:

```
 -1 25 15 10 -1    
 -1 27 18 18 -1    
 -1 15 24  6 -1    
 -1 -1 -1 -1 -1    
 -1 -1 -1 -1 -1
```

And when we sum it up with the output of the *2nd iteration*, we get:

```
 -1 -1 59 -1 -1 
 -1 -1 -1 -1 -1 
 -1 -1 -1 -1 -1 
 -1 -1 -1 -1 -1 
 -1 -1 -1 -1 -1
```

**answer** Only one 3x3 rhomb fits in to the matrix, so there's only one element left in the matrix, and that's exactly the sum of the only rhomb that fits: 59.

Comment: could you please show me an array from the example after 1st iteration? that would be awesome :P

Comment: where do I put the sum after summing? eg. (1,1), (2,0) (b), where does the sum go? (1,1) or (2,0)?

Comment: As for "where does the sum go" -- you can re-use the matrix, or create another one.

Comment: Penelope, take a look at this. Ur algorithm rocks however, I think there might be a little bug. :P http://imageshack.us/a/img801/4636/pomysl.png

Comment: @Patryk There, I made the changes to my answer. Yell if something's not right.

Answer (score 1):

If the question is about finding largest sum in diamond shaped 'kernel', then yes, there are faster algorithms.

The algorithm proposed by penelope is a good starting point -- however, when the rhomb size gets larger the required number of feeding in and out partial sums increases. This can be avoided with a 2-dimensional first pass, that integrates the values diagonally in 2 directions.

```
[ a b c d]  --> integrate a, a+f, a+f+k, a+f+k+p right down    
[ e f g h]      then integrate the elements in positions c,f,i etc. 
[ i j k l]
[ m n o p]
```

The downside of this approach compared to finding sums of aligned squares is that one has to calculate a separate set of diagonals for (x+y) is odd and for (x+y) is even; then the result comes from sampling 8 integrated sums instead of 4.

I believe the method (summed area) is most easily understood by integrating left to right and top to bottom

```
[1 2 0 3]       [1 3 3 6]        here every cell contains the summed area
[0 0 1 1]       [1 3 4 8]        of M[I][J] := sigma i=0..I,j=0..J m[i][j]
[1 0 3 1]  -->  [2 4 8 13]
[0 1 1 1]       [2 5 10 16]
```

To get the area(8..16,100..983) one has to access only the corner elements:

```
Sigma i=8..16,j=100..983 m[i][j] :== M[7][99]+M[16][983]-M[7][983]-M[16][99]
```

When the shape to be integrated is rotated by 45 degrees, we have to calculate two sets of integrals. If this was a chessboard, for white and black squares separately. Then each rhomb would be composed of N*N sized summed area from one matrix M_odd and (N-1)*(N-1) sized summed area from the other summed area matrix M_even (or vice versa). This scales to any rhomb size with equal complexity. (and with a possible optimization of adding up elements from the matrix m when N=1 or N=2 and using matrix M for squares N>2).

COMMENT: Perhaps this is equal to what penelope suggested, however, I couldn't figure it out because lack of generalization from 5-element rhomb to arbitrary sized.

Comment: can you please explain "the required number of feeding in and out partial sums increases" ? It's unclear to me, and I'm not completely sure if what you taught I want to do is what I actually proposed :)